# How to get compgen -c to output through javascript / node-cmd?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, javascript

I am using the node-cmd package to execute bash commands and use the output in my program.

**This works fine for most commands**, except for the compgen-c command which returns an error:
stderr returns: /bin/sh: 1: compgen: not found

err returns: {"killed":false,"code":127,"signal":null,"cmd":"compgen -c"}

This is my code:

```
router.get('/commands', (req, res) => {
cmd.get('compgen -c',function(err, data, stderr) 
{res.send(data)}
```

Expected output: a list of all Linux commands on my Lubuntu box.

Now, if i run 'compgen -c' in the terminal, it executes fine and outputs all 2227 Linux commands.
Linux error code 127 means (as far as i know) "Command not found".
The above code works flawless with other commands, like 'ls' etc.

My guess is that compgen behaves a bit different then normal commands. For example: whereis compgen returns (terminal): empty, while it is expected to return the location of the binary.

My question is: how to get the output of compgen -c into my node script?
 My goal is to have a list of all Linux commands.

Any help appreciated.